# Read folder content and convert the text file into array

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to load files into my sorting algorithms program. 
This is the folder instructions:

Folders:

```
512   1024   2048   4096   8192   16384 ...
```

Files in each folder:

```
1.txt   2.txt ...
```

Content in each file:

```
321
66
188
134
...
```

I managed to read all text files in each folder. Instead of reading each folder content manually, how can I read them all in one go?

```
void setup() {
    String url = sketchPath("numbers/512/");
    String[] stringData = null;
    int[] intData = null;

    runTest(stringData, intData, url);
}

void runTest(String[] text, int[] number, String url) {

    File directory = new File(url);
    File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        //println(file.getName());
        text = loadStrings(file);
        number = int(text);
        sortInteger(number);
    }
}

int[] sortInteger(int[] input) {

    int temp;

    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (input[j] < input[j - 1]) {
                temp = input[j];
                input[j] = input[j - 1];
                input[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    println(input);
    return input;
}
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: `for (int i = 512; i <= 131072; i *= 2) setup("numbers/" + i + "/");` ?

Comment: This is only a sample data, those files will be created by the user  so there will be no fixed size or name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already using the [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class to read the files from a directory. You'd just need to go one level deeper. It might look something like this:

```
for(File directory : new File("numbers").listFiles()){
   File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();
   for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        //println(file.getName());
        text = loadStrings(file);
        number = int(text);
        sortInteger(number);
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before but it didn`t work. it was keep crashing and sometimes I was getting Null error. When i tried this time it worked. there were 2 problems. First one was: it didnt like the file name path as: "numbers". The second problem was: the number folder had to be free of files... Thanks

Comment: @emre22 Note that you can use the `File.isDirectory()` function to check whether a File is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an utility library, I would recommend [Google Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) [`TreeTraverser`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser.html) class for the job. This allows you to iterate through the files and folders in the file tree through a single `Iterable`:

```
for(File file : Files.fileTreeTraverser()
                         .preOrderTraversal(new File("/root/folder"))){
    // handle each file and folder in the tree here
}
```

In addition to pre-order [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), the class also provides methods for iterating the tree in post-order and breadth-first order.